# Xcode falling images restart from top again when touching left or right

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, touchesbegan

When the code runs, a image will start to fall down from the top of the screen. I also have a touchesBegan with touches on left of screen and right of screen. However, once code runs and image is falling, when I touch the left or right side of screen, the falling image restarts and starts from the top again. This only happens for the first LHS or RHS touch. The following touches will not restart the falling image.

Why does this happen? How to amend the code?

The code I have is as follows:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

//When left hand side of screen touched, image will be Left.png, if RHS touched, image will be right.png
if(point.x < 240){

    stillImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Left.png"];

}else{

    stillImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Right.png"];

}
}

-(void)movement{

fallingImg.center = CGPointMake(img.center.x, img.center.y - 3);

}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{

fallingmovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(movement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: why is repeats on YES for your interval?

Comment: @AlexJ Because the image is falling down and every 0.05sec the method movement will repeat itself. If set to NO, image will not fall

Comment: I think it is unlikely to find your problem, since it seems that A LOT of relevant code is missing. Your movement method is changing `fallingImg` but your touch handling only change the `image` property of an `UIImageView` (I guess) variable called `stillImage`. What is this `fallingImg`? where do you set both of the above frames? What is the relation between `fallingImg` and `stillImage`, that changing one affects the other? Is there a reason you are not creating a new instance on every touch? It seems that touches has no affect on the movement, but a button has. Please provide more code/info